# Sort number array using lodash/Javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a string array as below.

```
let arr = ["1", "1+", "1-","2", "2+", "3","3+", "2-", "3-", "4", "10"];
```

I want the expected output as below.

```
["1+", "1", "1-", "2+", "2", "2-", "3+", "3", "3-", "4", "10"];
```

I tried the below code but it is not giving me the correct result.

```js
let arr = ["1", "1+", "1-","2", "2+", "3","3+", "2-", "3-", "4", "10"];
let result = arr.sort((a,b) => { 
  return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {
      numeric: true,
      sensitivity: 'base',
    });
  });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you need comparator for numbers and for signs.

**Gerenal concept:**
You can define sign priority like this:

```js
const signPriority = {
  '+': 0,
  'n': 1, // n = no sign
  '-': 2,
}
```

Where `key` is sign and `value` is sign weight we will use in comparator (`'n'` means "no sign").

Then we will split up array elements to number and sign, in comparator function and comparate them separetely:

```js
arr.sort((a, b) => { 
    // If numbers are different ...
    if (parseInt(a) !== parseInt(b)) {
        // Just compare a numbers 
        return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
    } else {
        // If sign matter ...
        // Extract sign from element or define as 'n' if no sign found
        const sign_a = ['+', '-'].includes(a.slice(-1)) ? a.slice(-1) : 'n';
        const sign_b = ['+', '-'].includes(b.slice(-1)) ? b.slice(-1) : 'n';
        // Compare signs using their weight
        return signPriority[sign_a] - signPriority[sign_b];
    } 
})
```

**Full solution:**

```js
const signPriority = {
    '+': 0,
    'n': 1,
    '-': 2,
} 

const arr = ["1", "1+", "1-","2", "2+", "3","3+", "2-", "3-", "4", "10"];

const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => { 
    if (parseInt(a) !== parseInt(b)) {
        return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
    } else {
        const sign_a = ['+', '-'].includes(a.slice(-1)) ? a.slice(-1) : 'n';
        const sign_b = ['+', '-'].includes(b.slice(-1)) ? b.slice(-1) : 'n';
        return signPriority[sign_a] - signPriority[sign_b];
    } 
})

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: I'd say the `.include()` + `.slice()` is not really needed. `signPriority[x.slice(-1)] ?? 0` will either give you the priority or zero.  And for `signPriority` you only need `{ '+': -1, '-': 1 }` If you wish to encode the default/no priority in the lookup, then you can use ` `{ '+': -1, '-': 1, default: 0 }`  with `signPriority[x.slice(-1)] ?? signPriority.default`

Answer (score 0):

Split each string using a regex word boundary. Use destructuring to get the number in string form (`an`, `bn`), and the sign (`as`, `bs`). If the sign is `undefined` use a comma as a fallback, since comma falls between `+` and `-` in the ascii table.

The return value should be `an - bn` (difference  of auto-casted numbers), and if that is `0` then use `bs?.localeCompare(as)` to sort by the sign.

```js
const arr = ["1", "1+", "1-","2", "2+", "3","3+", "2-", "3-", "4", "10"];

const getNumAndSign = str => str.split(/\b/)

const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  const [an, as = ','] = getNumAndSign(a)
  const [bn, bs = ','] = getNumAndSign(b)
  
  return +an - +bn || bs?.localeCompare(as)
})

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try convert string to decimal number and then compare.
For example if you convert "2+" to 1.9 and "2-" to 2.1 then you can compare values as a numbers.

```js
const arr = ["1", "1+", "1-","2", "2+", "3","3+", "2-", "3-", "4", "10"];

function convertToNumber(text) {
    const offset = text.endsWith("+") ? -0.1 : text.endsWith("-") ? 0.1 : 0;
    if (text.endsWith("+") || text.endsWith("-")) {
        text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
    }
    return parseFloat(text) + offset;
}

const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => {
    return convertToNumber(a) > convertToNumber(b);
});
console.log("Sorted: ", sorted);
```